# \@currentlabelname and custom counter

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

Suppose I have a counter, say, count. I can do something like this

```
\setcounter{count}{0}
\refstepcounter{count}\thecounter{count}\label{cool}
\ref{cool}
```

This will give me "1" in the end. Now, I would like to be able to use `nameref` in the following way (which doesn't quite work, and which is the reason why I ask this question)

```
\setcounter{count}{0}
\refstepcounter{count}\thecounter{count}
\@currentlabelname{awesome:\thecount}}\phantomsection\label{cool}
\stepcounter{count}
\nameref{cool}
```

I would like the result to be `awesome:1`, but it will be `2` in this case, because when I do `nameref`, `\thecount` gives value `2`. The problem is that `\thecount` doesn't save the value at the point it's called. How do I fix this?

As a side note, something like `\tag` (for equation) might work. For example, if I have `\tag{awesome:\thecount}\label{cool}` and have `\eqref{cool}` later on, I actually get the correct result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\thecount` needs to be expanded for `\@currentlabelname`. Otherwise the reference contains `\thecount` and the current number is printed in the references.

```
\edef\@currentlabelname{awesome: \thecount}
```

or

```
\protected@edef\@currentlabelname{awesome: \thecount}
```

LaTeX's usual protection mechanisms (such as `\protect`) will work, if `\protected@edef` is used.

Comment: This is indeed awesome. I'm using the one without protected ('cause I don't really know how protection mechanism work, but I will do this homework in the near future). Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for `\protected@edef`, never knew about that! Mysterious things within `hyperref` that needed protection were throwing errors on all changes of `\@currentlabelname` for me.