# Protection setting \@currentlabelname to give a "name" to a \phantomsection

Tags: hyperref, labels, nameref, protected-macro

This is a follow-up question to [nameref With Arbitrary Text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45061/nameref-with-arbitrary-text) and also [Refer to arbitrary text (without numbering and not by section)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438425/refer-to-arbitrary-text-without-numbering-and-not-by-section)

To summarize, the question was about how to reference to an arbitrary point in text, with an arbitrary string; and the prevalent solution was to use

```
previousText 
\phantomsection 
\label{L} 
textToBeReferenced 
[...] 
\hyperref[L]{textPointingToReference}
```

In these questions, the authors were content with defining the textPointingToReference at the point where the reference is inserted, but in my use case, I really need to define the string `textPointingToReference` (or the output of \nameref, if you will) at label creation.

This is because I want to access the name of the referenced object from multiple points in the document, and if I used `\hyperref[ObjectLabel]{ObjectNameExplicitlyGiven}` I would need to edit all instances of `\hyperref` if the object name changes.

I read in the `nameref` documentation that `\@currentlabelname` was stored in the aux file when calling `\label`. The use of `\phantomsection` has no bearing on the value of `\@currentlabelname`, so I naively tried setting `\@currentlabelname` manually, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%% outputs an object (in fact, a music score, that is a paragraph for TeX purposes) with label
\newcommand{\insertobject}[2]{
  %% #1 : reference of the object
  %% #2 : name of the object
  \makeatletter\edef\@currentlabelname{#2}\makeatother
  \phantomsection
  \label{#1}
  %% the objects I work with are music scores but this is irrelevant
  %% the commented line below would fetch and insert a music file named #1
  %\insert_music_score{#1}
  Object with reference #1 is here
}

%% Macro to print a cross-reference to an object
\newcommand{\objectreference}[1]{
    See object \nameref{#1}, page \pageref{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}

Lorem Ipsum

\insertobject{XYZ}{Object XYZ Name}

\objectreference{XYZ}

\end{document}
```

And of course this does nothing, `\@currentlabelname` as written by `\label` into the aux file is still "Section Title" and not "Object XYZ Name":

[image]

But then, I tried substituting the code of `\insertobject` into the document, and lo and behold, it works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%% Macro to print a cross-reference to an object
\newcommand{\objectreference}[1]{
    See object \nameref{#1}, page \pageref{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}

Lorem Ipsum

  \makeatletter\edef\@currentlabelname{Object XYZ Name}\makeatother
  \phantomsection
  \label{XYZ}
  Object with reference XYZ is here

\objectreference{XYZ}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Then I read [\@currentlabelname and custom counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170846/currentlabelname-and-custom-counter) and, not knowing a thing about protection, I tried substituting the line in the definition of `\insertobject` with `\makeatletter\protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#2}\makeatother` and then protecting the call to `\insertobject`, but it just gives me the classic "You can't use a prefix with the character @" error.

Any idea on how to get this going?

Comment: the \makeatletter/\makeatother must be outside/around the \newcommand.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by @Ulrike Fischer in the comments: "the \makeatletter/\makeatother must be outside/around the \newcommand."

The following MWE produces the intended output (second image in the question):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%% outputs an object (in fact, a music score, that is a paragraph for TeX purposes) with label
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\insertobject}[2]{
  %% #1 : reference of the object
  %% #2 : name of the object
  \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#2}
  \phantomsection
  \label{#1}
  %% the objects I work with are music scores but this is irrelevant
  %% the commented line below would fetch and insert a music file named #1
  %\insert_music_score{#1}
  Object with reference #1 is here
}
\makeatother

%% Macro to print a cross-reference to an object
\newcommand{\objectreference}[1]{
    See object \nameref{#1}, page \pageref{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}

Lorem Ipsum

\insertobject{XYZ}{Object XYZ Name}

\objectreference{XYZ}

\end{document}
```